# How to use apache Oozie java lib

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm new to Apache Oozie. As far as I understood, we can define a workflow of action either using a workflow file or a coordinator file, which are both in xml format, and submit it to the Oozie engine. However, there is a Oozie java library as well and I'd like to know how I can use this library? Is it for programmatically generating the xml files and submitting them to the engine? Can someone point me to an example please.

Comment: Oozie java library also serves same purpose as shell commands.You can specify the application HDFS app path and other required parameters in configuration object and run the workflows through java API.

Comment: so I do not need to create xml files manually, right?

Comment: You have to create workflow xml and place it in application path.Refer to http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_Examples.html#Java_API_Example

Comment: My question is actually whether I can generate the workflow xml using the api not manually?

Comment: You cannot generate workflow xmls using Oozie Java API.